# Why readline() from readline library don't accept UNICODE? ANSI C language

Tags: c, linux, unicode, readline

I written simple application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char *user_input;

    while(user_input = readline("> ")) {
        printf("%s\n", user_input);
        free(user_input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and when application is started it should take user input and after newline(enter key) should print what i had written.

It works for character like 'a', 'b' but not for Polish 'ł'. This char is coded and send as unicode. Tell me why? What i can do to tell readline to use UNICODE and show properly multi byte characters?

My readline version is 6.3

I add that my locale setting is:

```
# locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Changing locale to Polish and still not working:

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pl_PL.utf8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Still not working with conf below:

```
# export LANG="en_us.utf-8"
# bash
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_us.utf-8
LC_CTYPE="en_us.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_us.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_us.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_us.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_us.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_us.utf-8"
LC_PAPER="en_us.utf-8"
LC_NAME="en_us.utf-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_us.utf-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_us.utf-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_us.utf-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_us.utf-8"
LC_ALL=
#
```

Comment: did you try [`setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale)?

Comment: @Felix Palmen yes i tried without positive result.

Comment: Well it works for me (setlocale before the first call to `readline()`), `readline()` uses the locale. Maybe your locale isn't configured correctly on your system?

Comment: I added locale values in the question. And i have readline version 6.3.

Comment: I just done it :) thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a problem not related to the code but to some misconfiguration of the system.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the POSIX locale which doesn't support Unicode.

You can switch your entire user account to one of the utf-8 locales (en_us.utf-8 is a popular one). Consult your OS documentation about how to do this.

You can also set the LANG environment variable appropriately to temporarily switch a shell session to any locale, or use a specific locale name as an argument to `setlocale` (make sure the locale in question is installed).

Note that your terminal emulator may or may not show Unicode characters properly unless *it* uses the correct locale. The recommended way to ensure that is to switch your user account to a utf-8 locale.

This all works for Linux, the BSD family, and perhaps other Unix-like systems. Windows has its own unique set of quirks.

Comment: I tried also earlier with Polish locale and it is still not working. Try to see what i had added in question.

Comment: @sibislaw It looks like you don't have locales installed/generated. Use `locale -a` to list installed locales. If you don't find what you need, consult your Linux distro documentation. Also, you must call `setlocale` at the beginning of the program.